# Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax in alter table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to alter the auto_increment by laravel stament function and it is giving the error.

The complete error message displaying is SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1 (SQL: alter table `bills` AUTO_INCREMENT=9)

```
if($quantity[$i]>$qtny)
{
    Bills::where('id','=',$invoice_no)->delete();
    DB::enableQueryLog();
        DB::statement('alter table `bills` AUTO_INCREMENT=?',array('invoice_no'=>$invoice_no));
    dd(DB::getQueryLog());
    //return "<script>alert('Quantity is not available for product ".$item_name[$i]."');location.href='/create';</script>";
}
```

Comment: show the full error

Comment: Complete error is like SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1 (SQL: alter table `bills` AUTO_INCREMENT=9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable Placeholder is not allowed here.
So. I have done by this way,

```
DB::statement('alter table `bills` AUTO_INCREMENT = '.$invoice_no);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Variable placeholders](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html) are not allowed everywhere:

> Within the statement, ? characters can be used as parameter markers to indicate where data values are to be bound to the query later when you execute it.

`alter table` requires a constant here, e.g. you could not use something like `alter table bills AUTO_INCREMENT = (select max(id) from bills)`. Generally, everywhere you could do this, you are allowed to use placeholders (with some exceptions like `limit`, but those are then mentioned in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)).

So in this case you have to use the value directly:

```
DB::statement('alter table `bills` AUTO_INCREMENT = '.$invoice_no)
```

Comment: Btw: while this will solve your syntax error, a different question would be if you should actually reset the autoincrement value at all. It is usually not necessary or advised.

Comment: Fixed the concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the laravel query in two diffrent way you can tokenize variable

1) First method

```
if($quantity[$i]>$qtny)
{
    Bills::where('id','=',$invoice_no)->delete();
    DB::enableQueryLog();
        DB::statement('alter table `bills` AUTO_INCREMENT=:invoice_no',array('invoice_no'=>$invoice_no));
    dd(DB::getQueryLog());
    //return "<script>alert('Quantity is not available for product ".$item_name[$i]."');location.href='/create';</script>";
}
```

2) Second method

```
if($quantity[$i]>$qtny)
{
    Bills::where('id','=',$invoice_no)->delete();
    DB::enableQueryLog();
        DB::statement('alter table `bills` AUTO_INCREMENT=?',[$invoice_no]);
    dd(DB::getQueryLog());
    //return "<script>alert('Quantity is not available for product ".$item_name[$i]."');location.href='/create';</script>";
}
```

You can also write query below but your query will be wide open for sql injection.

`DB::statement('alter table`bills`AUTO_INCREMENT = '.$invoice_no);`

Comment: I have tried this both the method but none of them were working.